# Change div content when hover over link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to change the text of a `div` when hovering over other text.

How do I do it with JavaScript or jQuery?

```
<a href="#">change your div text</a>
<div class="original">
   <p class="old">this is my first quesstion on stackoverflow and i hope to be solved</p>
</div>

<p class="new"> the new text i want to add</br>
i will use big text really and i want to change it</p>
```

How can I replace the old `p` class with the new `p` class when hovering over the link above and how can I get it to return to the original class when the hovering stops?

Comment: this also works 4 me 
   
    $('a').hover(function () {
    $('.old').hide();
    $('.new').show();
    }, function () {
    $('.old').show();
    $('.new').hide();

    });

with css

    .new {
    display: none;
    }

i don't know why that post removed ?? iam new at stack-overflow ?
but that is also the same thing 
how to stay for a while in the new text (to make copy or whatever) ? it disappears automatically and i can't reach to the new text ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use jQuery, you're likely looking for the [`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) function.

It accepts either one or two handlers for when the mouse enters (and exits) the element.

```
var old = $(".old").html();
var now = $(".new").html();
$("a").hover(function(){
    $(".old").html(now);
}, function(){
    $(".old").html(old);
});
```

This stores the text of your original in `old` and the new text in `now` (`new` is a reserved word). The `mouseenter` handler changes the text to the new text and the `mouseexit` handler changes it back to the original.

For this to work, you'll need to set your new text to `hidden` (see demo).

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/AstroCB/42gV5/)

Comment: yeah it works well 4 me, but how to stay for a while in the new text (to make copy or whatever) ? it disappears automatically and i can't reach to the new text to make a copy of the new text ?

Comment: @CssMan Sure: take a look at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/AstroCB/42gV5/3/). It waits 5 seconds before changing back to the old text. If you want to change the amount of time, change the `5000` in the `setTimeout` (it's in milliseconds). By the way, if my answer worked for you, please consider [accepting it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the grayed-out checkmark next to it so that we both [gain reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: what i need exactly : 1- when hover over link <a> it changes old text to new 2- i can move to new text without disappear to make a copy or to read well 3- when hover out new text returns to old one ! i hope it clear now, but i don't need it limited by time , i need it to be limited when mouse out of new text,  and thanks 4 your efforts

Comment: may i ask another question please, if i want also when hover out of both link and new text it return to old one, cause in previous case when hover out from a link i still have new text

Comment: @CssMan Well, that took a bit of tinkering: what you're asking for is technically impossible since you want it to check if the user is hovering on the new text while also hovering on the link (if that makes sense). However, I did manage to get it to work the way you described by giving the user a half second to hover over the paragraph before it changes back to the old text. Check it out [here](http://jsfiddle.net/AstroCB/42gV5/7/).

Comment: that it's exactly, worked very well now >>> thanks very much bro

Answer (score 0):

The answer of @AstroCB is correct.

@Css Man: for your extra requirement, you could use setTimeout method.

```
var old = $(".old").html();
var now = $(".new").html();
$("a").hover(function(){
    $(".old").html(now);
}, function(){
    setTimeout(function() {
    $(".old").html(old);
    }, 2000);
});
```

See demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Teddy_Heaven/42gV5/2/

UPDATE: For new 4 steps require:

```
var old = $(".old").html();
var now = $(".new").html();
$("a").hover(function(){
    $(".old").html(now);
}, function(){
    // make time to change your mouse from <a> to <p> (here is 2s)
    var timer = setTimeout(function() {
        $(".old").html(old);
        // if timeout, unbind (A)
        $(".old").unbind('mouseenter mouseleave');
    }, 2000);

    // if you hover <p>, there are new business (A)
    $(".old").hover(function() {
        clearTimeout(timer);
    }, function() {
        $(".old").html(old);
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Teddy_Heaven/42gV5/6/

Comment: yeah u r right, and both you and @AstroCB r right, but i don't need it by time, what i need that when hover out the new text it returns to old one !?

Comment: what i need exactly : 1- when hover over link <a> it changes old text to new 2- i can move to new text without disappear to make a copy or to read well 3- when hover out new text returns to old one ! i hope it clear now, and thanks 4 your efforts